# how to translate a java runnable example to clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I'm a little bit confused as to how the Runnable block can be translated from this example:

http://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api

```
    Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(RECORD_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder.finish();
        }
    });
```

The bit of code I am confused with is this:

```
   Runnable(){... public void run() {... }}
```

Comment: Uhm, don't printStackTrace() an `InterruptedException`... At the very least, you should `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in the catch block

Comment: I would probably be better (safe and more readable) to use either a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), the `Thread` based approach with `sleep()` should be avoided at all costs! Doesn't really help with translation however...

Comment: Do you need to translate it one to one? Programmaticaly you would call (-> Thread. .run) in Clojure i think.

Comment: is the new Runnable(){} the same as reify?

Comment: In clojure you have no need of using plain Runnable object, there are other ways of handling concurrency and threads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of note, clojure functions implement Runnable.

```clj
user=> (ancestors clojure.lang.AFn)
#{clojure.lang.IFn
  java.lang.Object
  java.lang.Runnable
  java.util.concurrent.Callable}
```

So you could pass a fn directly to `Thread`'s constructor.

```clj
(def stopper 
  (Thread.
    (fn []
      (try
        (Thread/sleep RECORD_TIME)
        (catch InterruptedException e
          (.printStackTrace e))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably via [future](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/future):

```
(def recorder ( /*...*/) )
(def recorded (future (Thread/sleep RECORD_TIME)  (.finish recorder) recorder))
```

Then dereference it:

```
@recorded
```

Answer (score 3):

In the original message I understood that the question was that how to implement an interface (java.lang.Runnable in this case). That can be done with reify.

```
(reify java.lang.Runnable
  (run [this]
       (try
         (Thread/sleep RECORD_TIME))
         (catch InterruptedException e
           (.printStackTrace e))))))
```

Of course if you just wanted to execute a set of expressions in a separate thread you'd want to use eg. (future) as robermann mentioned above.